# ADF-Jdeveloper How to set the first value by default of a RichSelectOneChoice?

Tags: oracle-adf, weblogic12c, jdeveloper, jspx

I have a RichSelectOneChoice that is populated from a LOV, the default value is null, I know that it is a bad practice to leave default values in a SelectOneChoice but the user requires it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post how you solved this, please ?

Comment: Hi @user3739902 this is the answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/41770716/5120410, greatings.

Comment: Thanks I'll try that

Comment: Let me know @user3739902.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know is a bad practice set default values in comboboxes,

In my solution I set the default value in the current row of my viewModel of the field that I want to be selected by default in my select on choice, before to go to that page.

It´s something like this:

```
rowViewObjectRow.setCodeFieldReferenceSelectOneChoice(0);
```

The value "0" always be in the lov,  is a bad practice, and if you  find another solution without set the value by default  could be better.

Answer (score 0):

The RichSelectOneChoice has an attribute called value, setting that value will set the default value. Selection comes from af:selectItems or other selectItem(s) alternatives, so there are no contradictions there!

Comment: Thank you very much, this works for other purposes, I have implemented another solution.